# Powershell: How to rename all ".jpg" within folders?

Tags: rename

I have 1 picture in each of the folders and i want to rename them all to "ISO".
i want it to look something like

Folder1
    -sub1
        ISO.jpg
    -sub2
        ISO.jpg
    -sub3
        ISO.jpg
and so on.

right now all the pictures under sub# have different names, i want to rename them all to ISO
This is what i know to do with renaming

Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “ “,”ISO” }

i know this will replace all the spaces with ISO, but that's not what i want.
my main question is what the first argument for -replace should be regardless of the file name.

Comment: `-replace` takes a regex as the first parameter, so `-replace ".*", "ISO.jpg"` would do it. But if the name you want is fixed, why not just `-NewName { "ISO.jpg" }` ?  (This isn't posted as an answer because you're going to have to do something to work with subfolders, and to rename only the files you want, not every file)

Comment: `Dir *.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace '$_.name','ISO'  }`, try this out and let me know if it works (sorry not tested).

Answer (score 0):

Here my version , obviously if there are more jpegs inside a subfolder it could raise an exception :

```
Get-ChildItem .\sub*\*.jpg | rename-item -NewName ISO.jpg
```

Comment: this is it! thanks so much. This works great in my case since i only have 1 picture in each folder